# Form gets focus when I am using VBA editor

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

This is very annoying.
I am editing the VBA code behind a form in Access 2016 and for no apparent reason the form appears in front of the editor.  This happens every few minutes.  Any ideas why and how to stop it happening?
Thanks in advance,
Taffy

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to a form being open with a timer. You want to ensure that no forms or code run on startup, or that while editing code you have any form (even hidden and non visible) not loaded with any timer event running. Not only will such forms "often" grab the focus as  you note, but such forms also often cause erratic behaviours in the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0):

Answer seems to be to have the form open in design view, rather than form view, whilst editing the code behind it.